# Filter using wildcard characters on CSV format text

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

How can I filter the results of Excel data that seems to be formatted like CSV.

I will need to filter OUT all of the following:

- Cells in Column A containing "SRV" followed by some numbers
- Cells in Column A containing "RMA" followed by some numbers/letters
- Cells in Column A where the values start with "00"
- Cells in Column A where the values start with "R11"
- Cells in Column A where the values start with "111" IF the cell in Column AB (same row) is blank
- Rows where the cells in Columns C, D, and E are blank

The cells in Column A look like formulas, probably because this was a CSV file saved as an .xls.

Examples:
="SRV3121410001" ="RMA8111C" (should both be filtered out)

I planned on highlighting the cells to keep in yellow and then auto-filtering from there. Right now it's highlighting all of column A, so I don't believe I have my wildcards written correctly.

```vb
Sub AutoFilterMachines()

Dim count, i As Long
Dim Active As Worksheet

Set Active = ActiveSheet

count = Active.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
i = 2

Do While i <= count

    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "SRV*" _
      And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "00*" _
      And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "RMA*" Then

        Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

    End If

    i = i + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Boolean operators like `<>` don't support wildcards.

You can use `LIKE` instead.

Eg

```
If Not Cells(i, 1).Value LIKE "SRV*"
```

Etc